# reference valueobject collection from entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I map the value of an object collection using fluent mapping?

I am trying:

```
HasMany<DateTimeRentPriceDetailsMap>(x => x.RentPriceDetails);
```

where `DateTimeRentPriceDetail` is an `IList<DateTimeRentPriceDetail>`

`DateTimeRentPriceDetails` is a value object with 2 fields.

I am getting an error, which says that I am referencing an unmapped class, but the class is mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be mapping to the entity not the entity's map.  Depending on which table the foreign key is stored you may need to specify the column name but the below mapping references a collection of entities.

```
HasMany<DateTimeRentPriceDetails>(x => x.DateTimeRentPriceDetail)
```

Comment: youre right , what a shame ... iam now over 17hours in front of computer and my mind is like .. thanks a lot :)